# I have been sanctioned by my country's Higher Education Commission after being accused of plagiarism. What can I do?

Tags: plagiarism, research-misconduct

I am a professor in a public university and have been accused of plagiarism by an anonymous letter to the Higher Education Commission (HEC) of Pakistan.

The anonymous letter framed two charges:

1. It accused four scientists of submitting a plagiarized manuscript in Laser Surgery and Medicine, a prestigious US journal. As a proof the accuser attached an email of rejection on the basis of high similarity index from the editor of the journal addressed to the corresponding author. I have been listed as a co-author, whereas the email of rejection is addressed to seven email addresses.
2. In second allegation a reference of 2005 of the editor of a Pakistani journal is mentioned. The editor accused the corresponding author of submitting an article which was already published in a journal, i.e. attempted self-plagiarism. The manuscript was not published but the editor declared that the corresponding author and his co-authors were blacklisted from the journal without mentioning the names of co-authors. Unfortunately the corresponding author in both cases is the same person and the co-authors in both cases are unclear.

My name is listed as a co-author by the anonymous letter and I was completely unaware of both the incidents. But HEC has black-listed all four people accused, including me, for two-years.

What can I do?

Comment: I do not understand. Are you a coauthor or not? If so, did you and/or your coauthors plagarize?

Comment: Some aspects of your question do not match information available on news outlets. Namely a newspaper states that "**The journal editor** [...] found the work to be plagiarised and contacted Pakistani authorities" No mention of an anonymous letter. Furthermore, your defense in the article is "They blacklisted me [...] on the basis of a research paper which was never published anywhere" not that there is uncertainty about your co-authorship.

Comment: Besides, obviously, the fact that the plagiarism was detected prior to publication does not mean it did not happen.

Comment: [An article of reference on the matter.](http://www.dawn.com/news/1178465)

Comment: Did someone fraudulently put your name on their paper or papers without your knowledge?

Comment: To the OP, what @BillBarth is asking in the above comment is the key to your question. If your name was put on the paper(s) with your knowledge and if they can prove it, I don't think you have a case.

Comment: The article I cite is indeed the one linked by @jakebeal.

Answer (score 18):

Your question is weirdly vague on one important question, namely *whether you actually are/were a co-author of the two questionable submissions*. I am not sure how one can be "alleged" as a co-author - isn't that entirely clear and a completely black-white, yes-no question? Is your name on these papers?

Even if the HEC does not publish the name of the co-authors, *you* should still know whether you actually were a co-author of this publications or not.

The question *"what can I do?"* very much depends on your answer to this.

**If yes:**

You have presumably been sanctioned correctly. Trying to weasel out of your penalties based on formalities will likely only reflect worse on you. Accept the 2-year blacklisting and move on.

**If no:**

This then should be a clear-cut case of misjudgement, and following the formal appeal procedure whatever it is should definitely work out in favour of you. Your university should support you in this if the case is actually "I was blacklisted for a paper submission that has nothing to do with me".

Comment: Agree, especially with the "if yes" part.  Also it's not clear what exactly "blacklisting" means here.   If it's just that you can't publish, then the two years will pass quickly while you do (original!!) research and build a backlog of good papers to submit.  Not such a big deal if you have a permanent job?!

Comment: If someone fraudulent added OP's name to these papers, they may have no knowledge of what happened. It sounds like they were rejected before publication, so this could have happened entirely in private. If there was no hearing by the HEC, then OP's first knowledge of it may have been when the blacklisting was handed down.

Comment: @BillBarth That's a possibility, even though it seems to me very unlikely that the HEC would not first investigate (i.e., question) the respective individuals, and during this investigation something like "hey, I have never seen this paper - why am I a co-author of this??" would have come up.

Comment: The circumstances don't look good. Especially if the linked article is correct, but it has to be asked.

Comment: It's possible that, because of different dialects of English, "alleged as co-author" doesn't mean "alleged to be a co-author" but rather "alleged to have plagiarized because I am a co-author".

Comment: @AndreasBlass Normally all authors must approve a paper for it to be published and as such there's no difference. It's your responsibility to check for plagarism in papers which you have authored or co-authored.

Comment: @Murphy I would assume that Andreas means that it is "alleged" that the paper has been plagiarised, and not that the OP was a co-author.

Comment: A point that may not be clear to everyone because things differ from field to field is that sometimes, every co-author is contacted by the publisher and must agree explicitly to the publication or submission, and sometimes only the corresponding authors are asked to pledge that other authors consent to the submission and publication. In the second case, it may be the case that the OP was unduly listed as a co-author while he did not know about the paper. He should then turn against the corresponding author for fraudulently including him.